# mismatch between base 64 encode of windows and linux due to \n

Tags: linux, encoding, utf-8, openssl, base64

I found out the base 64 encoded string in .net using the following command in windows:

```
 Console.WriteLine(System.Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("4")));
```

which comes out to be :

```
NA==
```

After that i found out the base64 encoded string in linux using the following command :

```
openssl enc -base64 <<< '4'
```

which comes out to be:

```
 NAo=
```

After reading a lot from other post i made sure that in windows it uses the `utf-8` encoding. But, now problem is with i think `\r\n` or `\n`. So how do we rectify that?

Comment: Can you replace all instances of `\r\n` in the string with `\n` before converting to base64 on Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pipe in the value from echo and suppress the line feed instead:

```
echo -n '4' | openssl enc -base64
```